# Hierarchical List from recursive sql query

Tags: sql, oracle, recursion, sql-order-by

so I have sql table `tab` with father (c_id_1) and child (c_id_2) information

```
      C_ID     C_ID_1     C_ID_2
---------- ---------- ----------
         1          1          4
         2          1          5
         3          1          6
[...]
```

this means that `1` is the father of `4`, `5` and `6`
I am using a recursive query like described here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_and_recursive_queries_in_SQL

```
WITH R ( C_ID, C_ID_1 , C_ID_2, HIE) AS
(
    SELECT C_ID, C_ID_1 , C_ID_2, 1 as HIE FROM tab WHERE C_ID_1=1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT A.C_ID , A.C_ID_1, A.C_ID_2, B.HIE+1 FROM tab A
    INNER JOIN R B ON A.C_ID_1 = B.C_ID_2 
)   
SELECT * FROM R;
```

This generates a list including all father child information starting at `1` with a column `HIE` indicating the level of the entry

```
      C_ID     C_ID_1     C_ID_2        HIE
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1          1          4          1
[...]
         4          1          2          1
         5          1          7          1
[...]
         6          2          3          2
         7          2          8          2
         8          2          9          2
         9          3         10          3
[...]
```

How would I reorder that result to get Hierarchical List that would place all the children under their father looking like this:

```
      C_ID     C_ID_1     C_ID_2        HIE
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1          1          4          1
[...]
         4          1          2          1
         6          2          3          2
         9          3         10          3
         7          2          8          2
         8          2          9          2
         5          1          7          1
[...]
```

This way the top element of any given row is either `C_ID_1[i]==C_ID_1[i-1]` or `C_ID_1[i]==C_ID_2[i-1]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use this clause SEARCH DEPTH FIRST BY C_ID_2 SET order1, and with order by order1 like below. For more details see this page https://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/recursive-subquery-factoring-11gr2

```sql
WITH R ( C_ID, C_ID_1 , C_ID_2, HIE) AS
(
    SELECT C_ID, C_ID_1 , C_ID_2, 1 as HIE FROM tab WHERE C_ID_1=1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT A.C_ID , A.C_ID_1, A.C_ID_2, B.HIE+1 FROM tab A
    INNER JOIN R B ON A.C_ID_1 = B.C_ID_2 
)
SEARCH DEPTH FIRST BY C_ID_2 SET order1   
SELECT * FROM R
ORDER BY order1
;
```